# problems with tr1/random

Tags: c++, random, tr1

I tried to create a series of random numbers using uniform distribution whose limits are given from a file.

```
void initialize ( string file_in_name )
{
  ifstream file_in;
  int i;
  int j;
  //lbound= lower value bound, ubound=upper value bound
  double lbound;
  double ubound;

  file_in.open ( file_in_name.c_str ( ) );

  if ( !file_in )
  {
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Initialize - Fatal error!\n";
    cout << "  Cannot open the input file!\n";
    exit ( 1 );
  }
//
//  Initialize variables within the bounds
//
  for ( i = 0; i < NVARS; i++ )
  {
    file_in >> lbound >> ubound;

    for ( j = 0; j < POPSIZE; j++ )
    {

      population[j].lower[i] = lbound;
      population[j].upper[i]= ubound;
      population[j].value[i] = randval ( population[j].lower[i],population[j].upper[i] );
    }
  }

  file_in.close ( );

  return;
}
```

where randval is the following function

```
double randval ( double low, double high )
{
  double val;
  mt19937 generator;
  uniform_real<double> distribution(low, high);
  val = distribution(generator);
  return ( val );
}
```

The distribution I use is from tr1/random, but every time I use execute the code, the results are out of bounds. To be more specific, the file I give has lower and upper bounds equal to -180 and 180 respectively and the values are of order 10^12.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You shoulldn't create a new random generator instance on every call of the function.

Comment: `generator` doesn't seem to be initialized, so you're passing garbage.

Comment: I suppose that I should create the mt19937 only once outside randval and call it every time I need it, shouldn't I?

Comment: I removed the generator from the randval function, used it as a global generator and  initialized it once, using 

    generator.seed((unsigned int)time(NULL));

but the problem remains